# Some concerns about using survival analysis in non-prospective designed study

Tags: survival, censoring

1. I'm doing survival analysis using medical record, so the design is non-prospective. Is it alright to do so and is there any specifics I should concern?
2. Suppose we are focusing on how long it takes for a new tumor to recur after surgery. According to the guideline, patients should come back for reexamination in every 3 months after surgery. But it's totally up to the patients. So the majority will come back around 80-100 days. And only few would come in less than 80 days or more than 100 days after surgery.

   The question is: will the survival curve plummet around 800-100days, as most events will be distributed within that interval?

   My thinking: those events that are expected to occur in 100 days WILL occur by their first revisit, and those that can last beyond 100days will be censored (and may be detected in the following revisit). Therefore, the above question doesn't show sound reasoning. However, the uneven distribution of revisit time will surely result in the clustering of censoring time around 80-100 days. So my last question is, if the distribution of censoring is uneven across time, will it change the survival curve fundamentally?